# probability of finding the system in the ground state

Tags: probability, eigenvalue, two-level-system

$\renewcommand{\ket}[1]{\left \lvert #1 \right \rangle}$

> Assume that a quantum mechanical system is described by two orthonormal states $\ket{+}$ and $\ket{-}$, defined by the property of being the eigenstates of a self-adjoint operator A:
>
> $$A\ket{+} = \ket{+} \qquad A \ket{-} = -\ket{-}$$
>
> Suppose that the hamiltonian $H$ acts as 
>   \begin{align}
> H \ket{+} &= \eta \ket{+} + e^{i\alpha} \ket{-} \\
> H \ket{-} &= e^{-i\alpha} \ket{+} + \eta \ket{-}
> \end{align} 
>   with $\alpha $ and $\eta$ real constants.
>
> Find the normalized eigenstates of $H$ and their energies.
>   Determine which eigenstate is the ground state (i.e. the state with the minimum energy - all other eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are called excited states).
>   At the time t = 0 the observable associated to $A$ is measured
>   with the outcome −1.
>   Immediately afterwards the energy of the system is measured. What is the probability of finding the system in the ground state?

I found
$$ \ket{E1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( -e^{-i\alpha} \ket{+} + \ket{-})$$
with eigenvalue $ \eta - 1$, and
$$\ket{E2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( e^{-i\alpha}\ket{+} + \ket{-})$$
with eigenvalue $ \eta + 1$.

I don't quite understand how to find the probability.
I also do not understand the second part?

Comment: In what state is the system after the measurement of $A$? And if your system is in a certain state $|\psi \rangle$, how do you get the probability to find it in another state $|\phi \rangle$ in a future measurement?

Comment: after the measurement A the system is in state -1 , I dont quite understand by notes. how to find the probability to find it in another stae

Comment: Using my notation, the probability is $|\langle \phi|\psi \rangle|^2$. This is called the Born rule and it is one of the central postulates of QM. Also note that the *state* can't be $-1$. The state needs to be a ket vector, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

The state -1 which you mention is an eigenstate of the operator A, and not of the hamiltonian. You showed that the hamiltonian and A don't commute since the hamiltonian wasn't diagonal in the basis of A's eigen states + and -. Ignoring the bra-ket notation for now,

|-> = $\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}} (E1 + E2) $

Now since E1 and E2 are orthonormal too (check by quick multiplication), figure out the probability that the state - goes to the energy ground state when measured.

Comment: how did you get this expression? i dont understand Also